# como esperar um metodo terminar para execultar o proximo em angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-7

Bom, estou fazendo um curso de Angular, estou tentando entender o conceito de Observables e Promisses, porém estou um pouco confuso, estou utilizando o Firebase para criar uma simples aplicação, onde eu utilizo autenticação por e-mail e senha
e para salvar os demais dados do usuário tenho que utilizar o id desse usuário autenticado e cadastrar no Banco.
Feito isso tenho então que utilizar o método do meu serviço que cria esse usuário e depois utilizar o método que salva os dados.
Seguindo essa ordem tenho que fazer o método de `SignUp(email,senha)` ser executado primeiro do que o metodo `setUserData(User)`.

```
> Metodos

SetUserData(user) {
    const itemsRef = this.db.object(`usu/${user.uid}`);
    return itemsRef.set(user);
  }



SignUp(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.SendVerificationMail();
        window.alert("BEM VINDO");
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }
```

***Obs: Os métodos são chamados no componente onde faço o two-way data binding com o formulário utilizando um método 'onSubmit'***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS é assíncrono, você pode trabalhar com callback pra isso, o primeiro método recebe o segundo método como argumento, após o termino do processamento do primeiro, ele encerra chamando o segundo:

```
function segundo(login) {
  console.log('segundo');
}

function primeiro(callback) {
  console.log('primeiro');
  callback();
}

primeiro(segundo);
```

Também rola fazer isso com observable, com promise:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Callback_function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable

Comment: Muito Obrigado, cara, funcionou aqui, dei um jeitinho e boa, funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é utilizar o subscribe, dentro dele você faz as chamadas. O subscribe vai esperar a função ser executada pra depois executar o que está dentro dele. Segue um link de um tutorial mais fácil de entender:

- https://medium.com/tableless/entendendo-rxjs-observable-com-angular-6f607a9a6a00

Comment: Muito obrigado ajudou muito, haha valeu mano !!

Comment: Por nada amigo!